Is it required requestAuthorization for registerForRemoteNotifications for tracking uninstalls
For our iOS application we need to track uninstalls using AppsFlyer for all our users.
According to the documentation to use AppsFlyer uninstalls it is required to call
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

But I saw code examples like this
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge], completionHandler: {(granted,error) in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        })

So it looks like if user chooses "No" we cannot call application.registerForRemoteNotifications() and cannot track uninstalls.
Is calling UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(...) required by iOS platfrom rules to call application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
Does it violate any iOS platform rule if we make application.registerForRemoteNotifications() call in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions without any conditions and without requesting permission from user if we are not planning send any remote notifications, but just tracking uninstalls using AppsFlyer?

Why don't you try it and see?
